# ¿Puedo correr Kotlin con Android Studio con errores de compilación que afectan a otras clases/archivos?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image: Captura WS AS]

Siguiendo [la guía oficial de conversión a Kotlin desde Java](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/java-to-kotlin?hl=es-419#5) doy con un ejemplo sencillo, que presenta errores de compilación en la clase Repository. Simplemente para trastear, he creado un "main" en Principal, donde lanzo las pruebas y desde donde NO hay ninguna referencia a Repository (la clase con errores de compilación).

Para mi sorpresa, no puedo ejecutar Principal.kt porque hay un error de compilación en Repository (insisto, a la que no se referencia en ningún momento desde la función principal). Jamás había abordado esta restricción en otro entorno. ¿Alguien sabe si hay alguna manera de relajar este comportamiento? Gracias.

Comment: "Jamás había abordado esta restricción en otro entorno" -> Si el proyecto necesita compilarse de manera previa a la ejecución (como es el caso con java y kotlin) cualquier clase que impida dicha compilación va a impedirte ejecutar el proyecto... porque no puede compilarlo. Comenta todo el código de las clases que tienen errores y listo. Hay IDE que si una clase no tiene uso la "eliminan" del build, lo que permite seguir trabajando con otras, pero no todos lo hacen

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B! Ya descubrí la manera. Saludos.

Comment: Ya intentaste comentar el contenido de tu clase Repository?

Comment: Gracias @RuslanLópez La idea era correrlo con fallos. Ya está solucionado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues parece que sí se puede ejecutar una función sin que compile todo el proyecto y habiendo errores en otros archivos/clases.

Simplemente en Android Studio hay que entrar en la entrar en la configuración de Run/Debug que se genera automáticamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahí, abajo, en la sección de "Before launch", eliminar Build, que es una opción que aparece por defecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Y ya se puede ejecutar! - aún habiendo fallos -